# IE inner ticks of the input range

Tags: css, internet-explorer, input, range

From MSDN I found this page, but it is no really good explanation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/hh465789.aspx

How can I get rid of the inner ticks in the input field range of IE. It would be cool to have it for all IEs.

[image]

```
::-ms-ticks-before, ::-ms-ticks-after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
::-ms-ticks {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
::-ms-ticks-before {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

::-ms-ticks-after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

::-ms-fill-upper {
    background-color:#ccc;
    display: none;
}

::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: #999;
    border: 0;
}

::-ms-track {
    color: #ccc;
    border: 0;
}

::-ms-tooltip{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> input type=range -ms-ticks-before,after, -ms-track </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <style>
        #inp1                   { /***(no css style)***/ }
        #inp2::-ms-track        { color:transparent }

        #inp3::-ms-ticks-before { color:red; display:block }
        #inp3::-ms-track        { color:yellow }
        #inp3::-ms-ticks-after  { color:lime; display:block }

        div  { margin-left:2em }
        span { font-family:'Courier New', monospace; white-space:nowrap }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id=inp1 type=range min=0 max=100 step=1 value=50 />
        <br>
        <span>
            #inp1 { no css style }
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id=inp2 type=range min=0 max=100 step=1 value=50 />
        <br>
        <span>
            #inp2::-ms-track { color:transparent }
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id=inp3 type=range min=0 max=100 step=1 value=50 />
        <br>
        <span>
            #inp3::-ms-ticks-before { color:red; display:block }<br>
            #inp3::-ms-track        { color:yellow }<br>
            #inp3::-ms-ticks-after  { color:lime; display:block }
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XMHR3MGVVbFQ4V3M/input-type-range-ms-css.html    (demo)

Answer (score 1):

f12>Emulation tab, which documentMode is your page rendering in.... works as advertised on win7/IE11

should be Edge...

File>Properties to find out which IE Security zone your page maps to....Intranet sites may be using the "Display intranet sites in compatibility view" setting...

add the x-ua IE=Edge meta to your document to over-ride GPO configured Intranet zone configured Compatibility view settings....

eg.

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is good for future problems. Thanks!